# Bootstrap Accordion navigation with dropdown icon-chevron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, accordion

I have a bootstrap nav-tabs nav-stacked list which needs to use accordion to collapse all lists except for the one most recently clicked, or with active children.

I have this working somewhat, but can't seem to figure out how to get the chevron to change direction unless clicked.

I formerly had this only set up to do collapse, and not accordion-collapse... so need some javascript advice to get it fully functional.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utcwebdev/NBcmh/17/
(uses normal bootstrap markup, plus a custom bootswatch css theme)

Here's the markup:

```
<ul id="sidenav01" class="accordion nav nav-department nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <a href="department-mathematics.php"><i class="icon-home"></i> Mathematics</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#li02" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav01', data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed"><i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>Programs </a>
          <ul id="subnav01" class="nav nav-list collapse">
            <li><a href="#1"><i class="icon-home"></i> Programs Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Undergraduate Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Graduate Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">Undergraduate Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Math Plaza</a></li>
            <li><a href="#6">UTeaChattanoga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#7">Placement Criteria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#8">Step Ahead Math</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#page">A Single Math Page</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#li03" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav02', data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed"><i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>Student Resources</a>
          <ul id="subnav02" class="nav nav-list collapse">
            <li><a href="#pimu">Pi Mu Epsilon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#schol">Scholarships and Awards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Math Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#advise">Advisement</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="directory.php"><i class="icon-group"></i> Staff Profiles</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);

    var parent = $this.data('parent');
    var actives = parent && $(parent).find('.collapse.in');

    // From bootstrap itself
    if (actives && actives.length) {
        hasData = actives.data('collapse');
        //if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return;
        actives.collapse('hide');
    }

    var target = $this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''); //strip for ie7

    $(target).collapse('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sody. Here is a fix which did not require changing HTML markup. Add the following js prior to var target:

```
    $(parent).find('.accordion-toggle').not($(event.target)).addClass('collapsed');
```

Credit due to a developer on this project.

http://jsfiddle.net/utcwebdev/NBcmh/24/

Comment: But if you have markup with css classes from bootstrap documentation like `accordion-group` and so on, all js work is done by bootstrap  plugins. In this case there is a bug in bootstrap and some work is needed. But the best choice is to use bootstrap existing code as much as possible. This bug will be fixed in near future I beleive. But it will follow the same style with `accordion-group` classes.

Comment: And if you do not rely on `data-parent` attributes it will not work for nested accordions. I just updated the answer, you can get code from here as an example.

Comment: Thank you for adding details and explanation. At some point in the future I will need to add nested accordions for additional nav items... but will probabaly wait until bootstrap bug is squashed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that bootstrap collapse plugin not fully implemented for accordions. It toggles collapsed css class only for clicked element.

```
 $(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), href
      , target = $this.attr('data-target')
        || e.preventDefault()
        || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
      , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()

    // this line
    $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')

    $(target).collapse(option)
  })
```

**UPD**
To fix this you just need to find all toggle buttons and do the same with them:

```
$(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '.accordion-toggle', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        parent = $this.data('parent'),
        $parent = parent && $(parent);

    if ($parent) {
        $parent.find('[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent=' + parent + ']').not($this).addClass('collapsed');
    }
});
```

And don't forget to add `accordion-group` classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/NBcmh/29/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Font Awesome 3.2.1, then in the css, use the following to call the changes:
`.collapsed .icon-chevron:before {content: "\f078";}
        .icon-chevron:before {content: "\f077";}`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add another level to the accordion?

```
<li>
    <a href="#li02" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav01', data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed">
        <i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>Page 2 </a>
      <ul id="subnav01" class="nav nav-list collapse">
        <li><a href="#1">Page 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav01.1', data-parent='#sidenav01.1' class="accordion-toggle collapsed">
            <i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>Page 2.2</a>
            <ul id="subnav01.1" class="nav nav-list collapse">
                <li><a href="#1">Sub-level 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Sub-level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#6">Page 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

I added this portion of html but it's not showing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/G3PqR/12/

Comment: For this accordion... No. It was only intended for a single subnav. But if you improve it for more levels, please note your work here.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a similar problem, however I have managed to find the solution for the accordion arrows to switch but I can't figure how to keep the active one always open while being able to collapse the others.