# Bootstrap, stacked navigation with accordion and problems with JSFiddle and TryIt

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, jsfiddle, stacked

I tried to create a stacked navigation with accordion. I found

[Bootstrap Accordion navigation with dropdown icon-chevron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637911/bootstrap-accordion-navigation-with-dropdown-icon-chevron)

which showed a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NBcmh/29/

I modified this to http://jsfiddle.net/oyk2beph/ which worked quite fine (not pretty but worked).

```
<!-- Department Menu
================================================== -->
<ul id="sidenav" class="accordion nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="accordion-group">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidenav" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="#cat31">Hochschullehrgänge für LehrerInnen (3)<span class="caret arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="cat31">
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#351">Hochschullehrgang11</a></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#268">Hochschullehrgang12</a></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#006">Hochschullehrgang13</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-group">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidenav" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="#cat34">Hochschul-, Universitäts- und Masterlehrgänge (3)<span class="caret arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="cat34">
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#321">Masterlehrgang</a></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#319">Masterlehrgang</a></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#320">Masterlehrgang</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="sidenav01" class="accordion nav nav-department nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  <li class="accordion-group">
    <a href="#li02" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav01' data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed">Menu1</a>
    <ul id="subnav01" class="nav nav-list collapse">
      <li><a href="#1">Item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">Item 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">Item 13</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-group">
    <a href="#li02" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav02' data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed"><i class="icon-chevron pull-right"></i>Menu2</a>
    <ul id="subnav02" class="nav nav-list collapse">
      <li><a href="#pimu">Item 21</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schol">Item 22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#links">Item 23</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-group">
    <a href="#li03" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#subnav03' , data-parent='#sidenav01' class="accordion-toggle collapsed"><i class="icon-chevron pull-right"></i>Menu3</a>
    <ul id="subnav03" class="nav nav-list collapse">
      <li><a href="#pimu">Item 31</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schol">Item 32</a></li>
      <li><a href="#links">Item 33</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="directory.php">Staff Profiles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--/nav-list menu-->
```

and used the provided javascript

```
$(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '.accordion-toggle', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        parent = $this.data('parent'),
        $parent = parent && $(parent);

    if ($parent) {
        $parent.find('[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent=' + parent + ']').not($this).addClass('collapsed');
    }
});
```

Then I created another test using the same source on a different environment https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWCXINDT91X6

There the system do not work any more.

Can someone please enlight me why it is working on jsfiddle but not on tryit?
And maybe also what I need to do to get my navigation working?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: Isn't it not working already?

Comment: whats wrong in tryit? its working.

Comment: jsfiddle is working but tryit is not working (at least not for me, stacked menu is ok but accordion not). Tried with Firefox 60.2.1ESR.

Comment: @asif Sorry, my wording was not the best: It works on jsfiddle but not on TryIt and also not on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the html of the tryit.  It's completely different.  It's not using bootstrap and instead using an inline event listener which only sets the display to block. From what I gather, there's no reference to bootstrap at all in tryit.

Comment: I tried to replicate the jsfiddle in tryit. I struggle with seeing why bootstrap is not be used. jsfiddle do not even mention bootstrap and it still works, tryit has a reference to bootstrap 3.3.7 but no accordion.